# Autofac override inject

Tags: c#, autofac

I have the following:

```
containerBuilder.RegisterType<CustomContext>()
                .As<CustomContext>()
                .InstancePerLifetimeScope();
containerBuilder.RegisterType<CustomContext>()
                .As<BaseContext>()
                .InstancePerLifetimeScope();

public class BaseContext : DbContext
{

}

public class CustomContext : BaseContext
{
}
```

What I am trying to achieve is whenever `BaseContext` is injected in the constructor of a service to pass the instance of `CustomContext` that is created using the `containerBuilder.RegisterType<CustomContext>().As<CustomContext>().InstancePerLifetimeScope();` and not create a new one.

Currently whenever a lifetime scope is created I have two instances of `CustomContext` around.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you tried that?

```
containerBuilder.RegisterType<CustomContext>()
                .As<CustomContext>()
                .As<BaseContext>()
                .InstancePerLifetimeScope();
```

Comment: Yes!. That is exactly what I am looking for. Thanks for reading the question.